# Create columns based on unique column values and fill

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Timestamp   id  lat         long
0   665047      a   30.508420   -84.372882
1   665047      b   30.491882   -84.372938
2   2058714     b   30.492026   -84.372938
3   665348      a   30.508420   -84.372882
4   2055292     b   30.491899   -84.372938
```

My desired result is to have:

```
    Timestamp                        a                       b     
0   665047     [30.508420,  -84.372882] [30.491882, -84.372938]
1   665348     [30.508420,  -84.372882]                    NaN
2   2055292                        NaN  [30.491899, -84.372938]
3   2058714                        NaN  [30.492026, -84.372938]
```

Where the unique values found in `df.id` become column headers (there can be several thousand of these), with their latitude and longitude as values.

The closest I have come is using:

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    dct[r.Timestamp].append([r.id, r.lat, r.long])

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct, orient='index')


                                0                                   1
2055292 [b, 30.491899, -84.372938]                               None
2058714 [b, 30.492026, -84.372938]                               None
665348  [a, 30.50842, -84.37288199999999]                        None
665047  [a, 30.50842, -84.37288199999999]   [b, 30.491882, -84.372938]
```

But I know using any sort of iteration is bad in pandas (and it's nowhere close to my desired result), and I'm sure there is a much easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

Set the index then `pipe`

```
df.set_index(['Timestamp', 'id']).pipe(
    lambda d: pd.Series(d.values.tolist(), d.index).unstack()
)

id                                      a                        b
Timestamp                                                         
665047     [30.50842, -84.37288199999999]  [30.491882, -84.372938]
665348     [30.50842, -84.37288199999999]                     None
2055292                              None  [30.491899, -84.372938]
2058714                              None  [30.492026, -84.372938]
```

---

### Option 2

```
cols = ['Timestamp', 'id', 'lat', 'long']
pd.Series({
    t[:2]: list(t[2:])
    for t in df[cols].itertuples(index=False)
}).unstack()

                                      a                        b
665047   [30.50842, -84.37288199999999]  [30.491882, -84.372938]
665348   [30.50842, -84.37288199999999]                     None
2055292                            None  [30.491899, -84.372938]
2058714                            None  [30.492026, -84.372938]
```

Comment: And I'm assuming the best way to grab specific columns would be replacing `d.values` with `d[['lat, 'long']].values.tolist()`?

Answer (score 3):

I think this does it with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
(df.groupby(['Timestamp', 'id'])
 .apply(lambda x: x[['lat', 'long']].values.flatten())
 .unstack(level='id'))

id                              a                        b
Timestamp                                                 
665047     [30.50842, -84.372882]  [30.491882, -84.372938]
665348     [30.50842, -84.372882]                     None
2055292                      None  [30.491899, -84.372938]
2058714                      None  [30.492026, -84.372938]
```

Comment: Is there a better way than the splat operator to avoid the nesting? I can avoid it using `lambda x: [*x['lat'], *x['long']]`.  Either way, this does what I want, appreciate it.